# Gnu make is not exporting variables to applications

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project where to build it I use a command such as
`make PLAT=some_string` and inside the Makefile $(PLAT) is set as expected. My problem is that it is not being set for applications called within the Makefile.

For example, I have a Python script called by a sub-Makefile that has:

`PLAT = os.getenv("PLAT")`
and it reports that PLAT has not been set.
In the top level Makefile I have also added `export PLAT` but even this is not working. I am finding this extremely frustrating why variables are not being exported.
I went so far as to add `$(info $(shell /usr/bin/env))` to try and see what is being exported and according to this PLAT is not exported even though $(info $(PLAT)) shows it set and I have `export PLAT` also set.
This is with Gnu make 4.2.1.

Here is a sample  Makefile, what am I doing wrong?

```
export PLAT
$(info PLAT: $(PLAT))

$(info $(shell /usr/bin/env | grep PLAT))
```

```
make -f test.mk PLAT=hi
PLAT: hi
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

If I set PLAT from the bash shell it works as expected, but I can't seem to be able to create environment variables in the Makefile itself to pass on to other applications from the command line.

Comment: It looks like this is a limitation of make where variables must be explicitly passed to $(shell) commands.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with GNU make 4.4.1. What version do you use?

Comment: This behavior was changed in GNU make version 4.4.  See the NEWS file: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS?h=4.4#n73